# In DDD: Commands that produce events that no one consumes

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-driven, event-driven-design, eda

I am applying Domain driven design in my project and I am running into a scenario where a user action translates into a command in one  of my bounded contexts and thus produces an event. However I see that none of my other bounded contexts would care about consuming this event. Essentially all this command is doing is saving/ updating state in my bounded context.

My questions are :

1. does a command have to produce an event ?
2. If so, does it matter that nobody is listening ?

Answer (score 2):

> does a command have to produce an event ?

Absolutely not.

If you were using `event sourcing` as your persistence strategy, then all of your changes of state would be "events".  But there's no particular reason that you *must* expose the event elsewhere.

[Hyrum's Law](http://www.hyrumslaw.com/) is one reason that you might prefer not to broadcast an event

> With a sufficient number of users of an API,
>   it does not matter what you promise in the contract:
>   all observable behaviors of your system
>   will be depended on by somebody.

Don't guess what information should be included in the event until you have enough data at hand to make a *good* guess.

> does it matter that nobody is listening ?

In an ideal world, not really -- in practice, costs may well figure into the decision.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not a necessity for a command to produce an event, though it is preferable.
   One of the most significant benefits of events is the ability to generate the state of the system as on a particular date/time from scratch. If you were to religiously bubble-up events for all changes in the system, you will be able to apply events sequentially and bring the system to the state of your requirement.
2. IMHO, it does not matter that nobody is listening at **that** point in time. I am assuming that you are persisting your event into an event sink/log as part of your application. Doing so has two benefits:

   a. If you were to discover a future requirement which would benefit from an event log, you are already a step ahead.

   b. Even if nobody ever consumes the event, as mentioned in the first response, being able to generate a state of the system as on a particular date/time is a cool ability to have.

The pattern of persisting events and deriving a system state has its roots in Event Sourcing. You would want to take a deeper look at it to see its benefits.

Answer (score 0):

> does a command have to produce an event ?

No, its not a requirement, a command can just modify a state of an entity without dispatching an event. As said in others responses you should require every state change to produce a **domain event** if you use *Event Sourcing*.

> If so, does it matter that nobody is listening ?

Yes and No.

- Yes because there is no good or bad model, only useful model, if no one is listening then your modeling is not really useful to anyone.
- No because domain event are called **invariant**, they reflect business event and change only when the business requirement change, and so they are part of your API (see the concept of published language).